# Designing rubrics for AP Computer Science-style free response questions

Tags: grading, ap-computer-science-a

When I create questions in the style of the College Board's AP Computer Science Free Response Questions, I always attempt to create authentic rubrics that reflect how such questions would be graded.  However, I have not found any clear guides about how to do this.  I have noticed a few trends, but I wonder if anyone else has more (or something more definitive):

1. If a method requires a return, making a return is typically worth a point
2. If parameters are given, utilizing them at all is awarded some points
3. If arrays are present, looping through them with no chance of an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is awarded 1-2 points. *(If you need to loop through a String, that could also go here.)*
4. Dealing with funny edge cases is often worth a point.
5. Utilizing the appropriate methods from other Objects passed in is often awarded a point, though no penalty is made if they *successfully* recreate the functionality that the Object would provide.
6. Appropriately comparing two array neighbors without out-of-bounds potential, if it's that kind of problem, would be 1/2 a point, and correctly comparing *all* neighbors would be an additional 1/2 point.

You can see rubrics for the 2010 exam [here](http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/ap10_comp_sci_a_scoring_guidelines.pdf) as a sample.  Obviously, being able to create high-quality AP CS FRQ rubrics would help get the kids used to such grading - it could be the grading style used on exams through the entire course.

Comment: No points for solving the problem?

Comment: Rarely, and only 1/2 to 1 point. The goal (if I can extrapolate) seems to be to award points for properly executed components, and build up the full score that way.

Comment: On #6, they don't use 1/2 point any more. They're all full points. So if I was creating a rubric from scratch I would only use whole points.

Answer (score 3):

In the weeks leading up to the test I typically only use the actual past tests for exactly that reason. But even when I don't use the released FRQs I still grade on a 9 point scale so they get used to it.

Here's a few more that tend to come up.

For return methods, create a variable of the correct type, do something to it, and return it.

If it's a constructor, it should initialize the instance variables.

On full class problems - either write a full class, extend an abstract, or implement an interface - it's usually a point or two for the class signature.

> Utilizing the appropriate methods from other Objects passed in is
>   often awarded a point, though no penalty is made if they successfully
>   recreate the functionality that the Object would provide.

Sometimes. And sometimes they explicitly say that you must use the previous method for credit. #3 on the test this year did that.

I also have a negative rubric point for any of the penalties. Destruction of data, unexpected side effects, returning from a void, that sort of thing.